# How to validate schema from OpenApi specification with my response in Karate?

Tags: java, json, karate, gherkin

I have OpenApi spec yaml file where I have schema like this:

```
"schemas" : {
      "bankFilteringBic_200_response" : {
        "allOf" : [ {
          "properties" : {
            "debtor" : {
              "example" : 1,
              "type" : "integer"
            },
            "creditor" : {
              "example" : 2,
              "type" : "integer"
            },
            "currency" : {
              "example" : 3,
              "type" : "integer"
            }
          },
          "type" : "object"
        } ]
      }
    }
  }
```

And my test is look like this :

```
Feature: print hello world feature

Background:
  * url 'http://localhost:8080'
  * def myRequest = read('classpath:bank-filtering.json').components.schemas.bankFilteringBic_request
  * def expectedSchema = read('classpath:bank-filtering.json').components.schemas.bankFilteringBic_200_response
  * def expectedTypes = {}

  # Extract property names and types from the schema
  * def schemaProperties = expectedSchema.allOf[0].properties
  * karate.forEach(schemaProperties, function(key, value){ expectedTypes[key] = "#" + value.type })


  Scenario: Hello World Scenario

  Given path 'bankfiltering/bic'
  And request { processingEntity: 'ULSBGB2B', csmAgentID: 'SIC', debtor: 'LOYDGB21063', creditor: 'BARCGB22', currency: 'CRC' }
  When method POST
  And path 'bankfiltering/bic'
  Then status 200
  And match response == expectedTypes
  And print response
```

But when I run it I am getting this error

```
[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] ERROR com.intuit.karate - assertion failed: path: $.debtor, actual: 0, expected: '#integer', reason: not equal

sample.feature:21 - path: $.debtor, actual: 0, expected: '#integer', reason: not equal
```

I just want to validate my response with this schema which I am retrieving from the my OpenApi spec. Where I am mistaking and how to fix the problem? I was reading https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#schema-validation but could not find a solution for this problem.

Comment: You have string values for `crc`, `debtor`, and `creditor` but your schema expects `integer`